# How to view Lumetri Scopes with a Masked selection

Tags: adobe-premiere

When I mask a selection, for example a small area of skin, the information shown in the Lumetri scopes is so small that I can't see anything.

Is there some way to make the Lumetri Scopes more sensitive, so that I can see the information for the masked area?

Answer (score 0):

Lumetri Scope shows anything on the screen area.

So if you scale your clip it will be bigger.

Comment: Oh I really wanted this to be true, unfortunately it made no difference. Thanks loads for your reply, I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: How does it happen? Can you provide me with more details?
no problem we're all here to help each other :)